# php geoNear mongodb 2.6 do not work

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

i have a shared mongodb version 2.6 and i nead to do a geosearch.
using this javacode on mongos shell work,

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear : "contenuti" ,
             near : { type : "Point" ,
                      coordinates: [ 8 , 45 ] } ,
             spherical : true ,
    maxDistance: 1000} )
```

but this php code do not work

```
$query=array("geoNear"=>"contenuti" , 
            "near"=>array("type"=>"Point",
                            "coordinates"=>array($longitudine,$latitudine)),
            "spherical"=> true,
            "maxDistance"=>$limite );

$ret=$db->Command($query);
```

dumping ret i recive dis messsage:

```
array(3) { ["code"]=> int(17304) ["ok"]=> float(0) ["errmsg"]=> string(37) "exception: 'near' field must be point" }
```

Comment: i'm an idiot,just nead to floatVal($longitudine,$latitudine)

Comment: No you're not! sometimes the silliest errors that drive good developers crazy